# How do I connect EBS to ECS Fargate?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, amazon-ebs

I am trying to connect the same EBS to multiple ECS instances running on Fargate. I have a Docker container of my app, the ECS Task and ECS Service are working as expected, but I can't find any way to connect EBS to the ECS Task.

Note: The app instances synchronize writes through a common agent so there won't be a problem with regards to concurrency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that. It is not possible. EBS only works with EC2 instances. EBS is not supported by Fargate (at this time). You would need to use [EFS](https://aws.amazon.com/efs/) with Fargate.